# Get hidden field value in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, hidden-field

How can I get the value of the hiddenfield in code behind?

```
 <telerik:RadRotator ID="RadRotator1" RotatorType="AutomaticAdvance" ScrollDirection="Up"
                ScrollDuration="4000" runat="server" Width="714"
                ItemWidth="695" Height="260px" ItemHeight="70" FrameDuration="1" InitialItemIndex="-1"
                CssClass="rotator">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="itemTemplate" style="background-image: url('IMAGES3/<%# this.GetDayOfWeek(XPath("pubDate").ToString()) %>.png');">
                        <div class="dateTime">
                            <div class="time">
                                <%# (this.GetTimeOnly(XPath("pubDate").ToString())) %>
                            </div>
                            <div class="date">
                                <%# (this.GetDateOnly(XPath("pubDate").ToString()))%>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="title">
                            <span>
                                <%# System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(XPath("title").ToString())%>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="buttonDiv">
                            <asp:Button ID="Button1" class="button" runat="server" Text="View" OnClientClick="OnClick"  />
        THIS HIDDENFIELD >>>>> <asp:HiddenField id="rssLink" runat="server" value='<%= System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(XPath("link").ToString()%>' />

                        </div>
                        <div class="description">
                            <span>
                                <%# System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(XPath("description").ToString())%>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:RadRotator>
```

The hidden field is inside a RadRotator and I am battling to get the value of it in code behind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use it's [Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property

```
var value = this.rssLink.Value;
```

**Edit:** for the telerik control it looks like you'll need to use FindControl on the Databind - there's an [article here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/rotator-server-side-events.html).

Comment: @FeliceM in that case there's a problem with your markup - first check that the designer is up to date. Is it inside another control? We'll need to see your aspx

Comment: @FeliceM make sure ID is capitalised

Comment: I have added the code. I think the problem is that it is inside a control and I have to leave it in there otherwise I will not get the correct value.

Comment: Ah - that would have been helpful to know in the question! Can you update it? I suspect you want the FindControl() method on the parent control but I can't know for sure without seeing your markup

Answer (score 2):

when you write something like that in your aspx file you will see that in the designer file you've got a generated property with as name the id of the field you used.

So in the code behind you can use this property because the classes are partial

```
var value = this.rssLink.Value;
```

like said before

Answer (score 2):

```
string hiddenFieldValue = rssLink.Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

If the Hidden field has the runat="server" attribute then you should be able to access it from the server side using 2 ways:

> 1- using the value property.
>
> 2- using Request.Forms["hiddenFieldName"]

Check this [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1832212.aspx)

Comment: Forms or Form? I don't have Forms, just Form.